# Error in code to paste contents

Tags: excel, vba, global, paste

I tried to make the following code in order copy the contents of several rows to copy their contents into the second row.

```
Sub PasteBetter()
Dim r As Range, cell As Range
   Dim rng As Range
Set r = Range(Range("A3"), Range("A3").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In r
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
        Set rng = Range(Range("A2"), Selection.End(xlToRight))
        Range(rng).Offset(RowOffSet:=1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next cell
End Sub
```

However, this hangs on the Range(rng).Offset(RowOffSet:=1).Select line, saying it misses a global variant. The only one called is rng which is defined in the row before it. What is my coding mistake here?

As to clarify, I am trying to make a file like this

[image]

Look like this
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to copy cells A2~F2 then paste it in to the cells A3~F3 basically?

Comment: @MutjaLee I am trying to copy A3~F3 behind A2~F2, and then A4~F4 behind the new elongated A2~L2. Looping this untill al is structured behind one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rng` is already a range. No need to wrap it into the method `Range()`.
So, this should solve it:

```
rng.Offset(RowOffSet:=1).Select
```

Yet, you might want to revise your code here:

```
Set r = Range(Range("A3"), Range("A3").End(xlDown))
```

to something like this (if possible):

```
 Set r = Range(Range("A3"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

Otherwise, it could happen that the range will go down to the last row on that sheet (Excel 2007+ more than a million) and your `sub` will run for quite some time...

### Update 1:

While the above solved the original code the following code is a much improved version of what should be accomplished.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteBetter()

Dim varArray As Variant
Dim strFinalarray() As String
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastColumn As Long
Dim lngColumn As Long, lngRow As Long

ReDim strFinalarray(0)
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    lngLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lngLastColumn = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    varArray = .Range(Range("A2"), Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastColumn)).Value2
    For lngRow = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
        For lngColumn = 1 To lngLastColumn
            If varArray(lngRow, lngColumn) <> vbNullString Then
                strFinalarray(UBound(strFinalarray)) = Trim(varArray(lngRow, lngColumn))
                ReDim Preserve strFinalarray(UBound(strFinalarray) + 1)
            End If
        Next lngColumn
    Next lngRow
    ReDim Preserve strFinalarray(UBound(strFinalarray) - 1)
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, UBound(strFinalarray) + 1)).Value2 = strFinalarray
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastColumn)).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

The above code should be extremely fast (almost instantaneous). This is due to the fact that access to the sheet is limited to the bare minimum. The more one accesses a sheet (read data from the sheet or write data to the sheet) the slower the code. In the above code all data is read into memory with one line of code `varArray = .Range(Range("A2"), Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastColumn)).Value2`.

At this point `varArray` is pretty much a replication of the sheet (starting at `A2`). Then everything in this array is moved into another (1-dimensional) array which is finally pasted to the sheet starting with cell `A2`.

### Update 2:

```
Sub SimpleVersion()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngColumn As Long
Dim lngCopyToColumn As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLastColumn As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    'Get the last row and last column for the sheet
    'Source: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba
    lngLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lngLastColumn = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'Loop through all rows and all columns
    lngCopyToColumn = lngLastColumn + 1
    For lngRow = 3 To lngLastRow
        For lngColumn = 1 To lngLastColumn
            'If the cell is not empty then...
            If .Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
                'Copy the cell over to the end
                .Cells(2, lngCopyToColumn).Value2 = .Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Value2
                'Increase lngCopyToColumn by 1. Otherwise,
                '  the same cell gets overwritten over and over again
                lngCopyToColumn = lngCopyToColumn + 1
            End If
        Next lngColumn
    Next lngRow

    'Not that everything is copied over
    '  everything below row 2 can get deleted
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastColumn)).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

This solution might be a bit easier to understand. Don't hesitate to ask if you have questions understanding it.

Comment: We have a good start here :) The first line alteration indeed ran the code, what happened next was indeed it ran infinite - causing a crash. However, when I used your suggested altered line it did not parse the macro giving the same error as before but then with your line. Would a Do/Loop function with "" to end it perhaps work better with my original line? Or do you see the error in your suggested code?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. It should have been `Cells` not `Range`. I corrected the line. Now it should work.

Comment: That got it and I was able to get it to function along 3 other macro's that I grouped together. Many thanks. :) At least I wasn't too far off this time around.

Comment: Today I came back to the office excited to try this all out, but there seem to be an error. If the file has more then two lines it fails to copy the lines and paste them behind one another. It simply keeps all the letters in single cells and moves the whole of it down a few cells... Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: The error with a lose excel file that looks like what I want to produce - instead of the file that I want to convert - is different. Now removing just the third row on A3. Making it more mind boggling. I am going to try a bit of a different code for this is illogical.

Comment: Tried the code of @Ryan Wildry and that works, but is a lot slower. If you still want to find out what is going. Here is an excel sheet of what I want to transform: [link](http://www.4shared.com/file/8-nBYoLice/PasteTest.html) and here is an "original" file that I load into Excel and convert that obtains a file like the excel sheet [link](http://www.4shared.com/file/hca_MkUfba/Gibberish.html)

Comment: While I haven't been able to download the files (too many pop-up windows, advertising, and requires scripts which I certainly do not enable on such sites) I still came up with new code. I sure hope that the above solution works for you.

Comment: I've added a revision as well below. It won't rely on a delimiter to split the cells, which maybe a bit more desirable. Especially if you don't know the type of data that's going to be stored in the future.

Comment: Yet, another minor update since @RyanWildry seems to be interested to find the perfect solution for this problem. I'm pretty sure there is much more that can be refined in the above solution.

Comment: I am sorry the site I linked to (a virtual HD) gave you that much trouble (I have no pop-ups etc.). Anyways, I thank you both for your help, I really do. However, with my very limited knowledge (first time using VBA) I don't get the extensive codes at all and they go right above my head. Dissallowing me to modify or understand/learn. My code may be crude, but it was simple and I could follow it. I think in order to succeed it needed a way with End(xlDown) how to stop it the cells were empty (or with End(xlUp) learn why it added white rows at the top).

Comment: @GMV I just added another solution which might be a bit easier to understand. Let me know if this is better to follow.

Comment: @Ralph fails to work giving a compilation error at lngLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Answer (score 1):

don't bother with copy and pasting ...try the below

```
Sub asdf()

    Dim a As Worksheet
    Dim b As Worksheet

    Set a = Sheets("Sheet2") 'replace with your source sheet
    Set b = Sheets("Sheet3") 'replace with your destination sheet

    For c = 1 To a.Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column
        lastrow = a.Cells(65536, c).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        b.Range(b.Cells(1, c), b.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(1, c), a.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value
    Next c

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

my original answer didn't solve the question.  update below:

```
Sub asdf()

    Dim a As Worksheet
    Dim b As Worksheet

    Set a = Sheets("Sheet2") 'replace with your source sheet
    Set b = Sheets("Sheet3") 'replace with your destination sheet

    For r = 3 To a.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        lastCol = a.Range("iv2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column 'get last column in destination row
        lastCol2 = a.Cells(r, 16383).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get last column in copy row

        a.Range(a.Cells(r, 1), a.Cells(r, lastCol2)).Copy
        a.Cells(2, lastCol).PasteSpecial
        a.Range(a.Cells(r, 1), a.Cells(r, lastCol2)).ClearContents
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: You should update this to clear the values per the original ask.

Comment: @RyanWildry thanks for the heads up...updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that doesn't rely on cut and paste:

**UPDATE:**

I had to make the range wider to paste all the values of the array. See below. Thanks for letting me know about that! I hope this one has been solved for you :)

```
Option Compare Binary
Public Sub MoveCellsOneRow()
    Dim LastRow             As Long
    Dim myrow               As Long
    Dim LastColumn          As Integer
    Dim mycol               As Integer
    Dim StartCol            As Integer
    Dim MyArray()           As Variant
    Dim ArrayCounter        As Long

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    StartCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    ArrayCounter = 0
    'Determine what the size of the array should be
    For myrow = 3 To LastRow
        LoopColumns = Cells(myrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        For mycol = 1 To LoopColumns
            If Cells(myrow, mycol) <> vbNullString Then ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
        Next mycol
    Next myrow

    'Resize the array once, redim preserve is an expensive operation
    ReDim MyArray(0 To ArrayCounter)
    ArrayCounter = 0

    'Populate the array. code below is almost identical to previous solution
    For myrow = 3 To LastRow
        LastColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LoopColumns = Cells(myrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        For mycol = 1 To LoopColumns
            If Cells(myrow, mycol) <> vbNullString Then
                MyArray(ArrayCounter) = Cells(myrow, mycol)
                ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
            End If
        Next mycol
    Next myrow

   'Dump the array contents, and clear the other cells
   'Made a change here to correct for the 'paste' range. Needed to be wider
   Range(Cells(2, (Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1)), Cells(2, (ArrayCounter + StartCol))) = MyArray()
   Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(LastRow, (Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1))) = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't follow the code and I rather understand what I am using. I am sure it will work but for my limited understanding you are also looping columns and I only wish to move rows which confuses me. Sorry, for being a noob. :s

Comment: It loops through every row for each column, then adds the result on row 2 at the last column index. If you've got something working, great. SO is also a place to learn and get different solutions! I hope this issue has been resolved for you :)

Comment: Used your code today, it works indeed although it a lot slower then the code originally posted at least it does not generate errors with more variable files. Still trying to wrap my head around the code though.

Comment: Check the revised method. It's a bit more complicated, it will add everything into an array then paste the results. The results are very quick.

Comment: Unfortunately this code did not manage to do the largest files. These files have about 1150 cells and the max row it created was 1086 cells (The first 6 cells of row 20). Not sure why that happened.... :s

Comment: Yeah, i found the error. Give the new solution a try :)